# For loop not incrementing (possibly a malloc problem)

Tags: c, malloc

I am porting code from an Intel XScale CPU architecture (ARM) to a i386 CPU Architecutre (Vortex86 CPU.
I am at a point where the code compiles and runs, but i am experiencing very odd behaviour with a for() loop in the software startup.

I'm initialising data buffers for 4 different sampling frequencies.
and 4 different channels, CH0, CH1, CH2, CH3, each with 100Hz, 20Hz, 1Hz, and 10Min sample rates.

sample = int.
buffers sizes are:

- 100Hz = 6000samples * sizeof(sample)
- 20Hz = 1200samples * sizeof(sample)
- 1Hz = 3600samples * sizeof(sample)
- 10Min = 144samples * sizeof(sample)
- The loop succeeds for ChanID=0
- The loop succeeds for ChanId=1, BUT reports "CH0 Initialised"... and so on... repeat

This is the loop:

```
// THIS DOESN'T WORK.. I don't know why...
// Initialise() performs a malloc x 4 for each channel for the sizeof(buffer)
// Initialise() also opens a serial port DeviceNames[ChanId], with the FD returned

    for (ChanId=0; ChanId < NUM_CHANNELS; ChanId++) 
    {
        if ((fds[ChanId] = Initialise(ChanId, DeviceNames[ChanId])) == -1) 
        {
            syslog(LOG_INFO, "Failed to initialise RT Ch%d", ChanId);           
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {   
            syslog(LOG_INFO, "Ch%d Initialised", ChanId);           
        }
    }
```

I have tried the following which seems to work without issue.

```
if ((fds[0] = Initialise(0, DeviceNames[0])) == -1) 
{
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Failed to initialise RT Ch0");            
    return -1;
}
if ((fds[1] = Initialise(1, DeviceNames[1])) == -1) 
{
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Failed to initialise RT Ch1");            
    return -1;
}
if ((fds[2] = Initialise(2, DeviceNames[2])) == -1) 
{
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Failed to initialise RT Ch2");            
    return -1;
}
if ((fds[3] = Initialise(3, DeviceNames[3])) == -1) 
{
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Failed to initialise RT Ch3");            
    return -1;
}
```

I have pushed the Malloc address pointer to the log, and it looks reasonable.

I'm wondering if the malloc process is corrupting the variables currently in the heap?

THe exact same code works fine on the ARM Architecture Intel XScale

Comment: Please try to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it. For example, what is `fds`? How is `fds` initialized? Same with `NUM_CHANNELS` and `DeviceNames`.

Comment: Have you tried this with optimisation turned off?

Comment: And if you build with extra warning enabled (like e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` for GCC or Clang), do you get any warnings for your code then? If you build and run with a sanitizer (build with e.g. `-fsanitize=address` or `-fsanitize=undefined`), what happens then?

Comment: What's the difference between `Initialise` (used inside loop) and `RT_Initialise` (used in subsequent if's)? What's `ChanId` type and what's `NUM_CHANNELS` value?

Comment: THanks 'some-programmer-dude' I'll work on that.  , fds[] is a list of file descriptors for the opened serial ports within Initialise(). they are ints, NUM_CHANNELS is = 4 (#define) Device names are relations to the serial port for each channel..  I don't see any of those as being the issue..  but I guess they could be...

Comment: Please don't describe your code, *show it*. In the form of a [mre] as mentioned before.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - using the following:
-Wall -O2 -fpack-struct -g3
Tomek - no difference, same function. I was removing detail for the example...
ChrisBD - not sure, sorry I'll look at the compile options. currently -O2 I can try removing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this line

```
if ((fds[ChanId] = Initialise(ChanId, DeviceNames[ChanId])) == -1)
```

is causing issue with the compiler optimisation when run within a loop or timing (as you state that `Initialise` is interacting with serial ports). This may be indicated by

> The loop succeeds for ChanId=1, BUT reports "CH0 Initialised"... and so on... repeat

Try:

```
for (ChanId=0; ChanId < NUM_CHANNELS; ChanId++) 
{
    int result = Initialise(ChanId, DeviceNames[ChanId]);
    fds[ChanId] = result;
    if (result == -1) 
    {
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "Failed to initialise RT Ch%d", ChanId);           
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {   
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "Ch%d Initialised", ChanId);           
    }
}
```

Other than that, is it possible that `ChanId` is set eleswhere and so replacing it with a local variable may work?

Comment: same behaviour with this code... BUT..  I compiled without optimiations ("-O2") and it that worked. So yes, it was a compiler Optimisation problem.
I also removed the -fpack-struct 
Thank you